# How can I import module if I have an absolute path in Python

Tags: python, sys.path

I need to import my module foo.py if I've got an absolute path (so module is located in "users/suv/desktop/pr1/pyth" but can be located in any different path as well) . I tried

```
  import sys

  MYDIR = "users/suv/desktop/pr1/pyth"
  sys.path.append(MYDIR)
  import foo
```

and I have the following mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stats", line 7, in <module>
  import foo
ImportError: No module named foo
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path

Comment: It looks like you're on a Unix-like system. Absolute paths usually start with an initial "/". Is that really your absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Afile.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/DIRECTORY')

import Afile
```